# Integration CALCULUS

Tags: calculus

I need help on problem based on integration calculus.

Q: how to integrate
$$\int\frac{dx}{1+\sin(x)\tan(x)}$$
Wolfram and integrate calculator does not help me.

Comment: What is next to do ?

Comment: Why do you say that wolfram does not help? [It does!](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1%2F%281%2Bsinx+tanx%29)

Answer (score 5):

**Hint**: Classical method seems to work here: $t = \tan\left(\dfrac{x}{2}\right)$ followed by partial fraction decomposition is a surefire way out.

Comment: you should use my hint to finish it as this is your homework, not mine.

Comment: @balla. Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange ! You must understand that, in this site, you will find people ready to help you provided you show your efforts and explain where you are stuck. This is not *http://do_my_homework.com*.

Comment: @balla, you have $t=\tan(x/2)$, then $dt=\frac 12\sec^2 (x/2)dx$, now replace the terms containing $x$ with corresponding term in $t$. Now try yourself